# Loading bootstrap font .eot in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, font-face, eot

Here's the font-face declaration in my customized bootstrap.css :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

All these bootstrap fonts reside in my virtual machine (192.168.137.4). When loading the page, IE8 always requires the font download, whereas there's no problem for every other browser (Chrome, Firefox and IE9,10,11).

When I tried to replace ../../ by some cdn links for these fonts (for example : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot) it just worked perfectly in IE8 but I still need to load them from local.

Please advise, what am I missing/what needs to be changed to fix this issue?

P/S : I did consult these posts but in vain :

-https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-prevent-ie7-ie8-from-downloading-font-face-files/

-[How to prevent IE7 from downloading all EOT files used for font-face declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804502/how-to-prevent-ie7-from-downloading-all-eot-files-used-for-font-face-declaration)